# OAuth2.0: Exception- FileNotFound when performTokenRequest

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, token, appauth

I am using AppAuth library for Oauth2 authentication.
https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android

I modified the urls as per my oauth provider.
I have specified a valid authorization endpoint, client id, redirect uri, token uri, response type (Code). I didn't find any way to add client secret.
When I run the app, I see web page in browser, enter the credentials and then redirect happens back to app. When the request to get token gets executed, I get an exception.
The token request is failing. Any idea why this would happen? The token exchange url is correct and I am not sure why it is complaining about file not being found at that particular token url.

W/AppAuthSample: Token Exchange failed

```
AuthorizationException: {"type":0,"code":3,"errorDescription":"Network error"}

    at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:244)

    at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:206)

    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <token_url>

    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)

    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)

    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)

    at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:239)

    at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:206) 

    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 

    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the AppAuth sample without errors? Maybe proceed like this:

- Follow the steps in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup/) to get a working solution
- Then repoint to your own Authorization Server to see if that also works
- Then update your app accordingly

It looks like the token endpoint URL is not right. Could you post HTTP messages? You don't need a client secret by the way, since a PKCE runtime secret is generated. See steps 8 and 10 of my more [advanced blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/) for how it should look.